# Codenameone Webbrowser issue

Tags: browser, codenameone

I am trying to display a webpage from codenameone application. It works fine in Iphone but not in andriod mobile.

```
public void showLoginForm()
{
    final Form loginForm = new Form("Login");
    loginForm.setUIID("Form1");
    loginForm.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    loginForm.setScrollable(false);

    try
    {
        WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser()
        {
//Overrides onStart and onLoad methods to load progress bars for page transitions.
        };

        browser.setURL(appsGlobalSettings.get(URL_KEY));
        loginForm.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER,browser);
        loginForm.show();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

}
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception? What specifically isn't working? Does the app crash?

Comment: In simulator and IPhone, I am not getting any exception. However in andriod, it shows the progress bar running and it is stuck at the same  screen. I haven't observed any logs.

Comment: What exception did you get? What is happening when you don't set the URL? Step 1 to solve a problem is good analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Check your URL. I suggest removing the override code and placing Google.com hardcoded as a URL and proceeding from there. Since it doesn't work in the simulator either make sure you are using Java 7 with JavaFX enabled, with that case it should show a browser and should work for a proper web address.

Answer (score 0):

Shai...It took some time to collect device logs.

But even that is intriguing.

I tried in two ways

1. No overridden methods in WebBrowser class and http://www.google.co.in as URL.

   ```
   public void showLoginForm()
   {
   InfiniteProgress inf = new InfiniteProgress();
   Dialog progress = inf.showInifiniteBlocking();
   final Form loginForm = new Form("Login");
   loginForm.setUIID("Form1");
   loginForm.setLayout(new BorderLayout());    

   try
   {
       //Log.p("Inside showLoginForm method");
       WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser()
       {

       };
       //browser.setURL(appsGlobalSettings.get(URL_KEY));
       browser.setURL("http://www.google.co.in");
       //Log.p("Set Broswer url");
       loginForm.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER,browser);
       //Log.sendLog();
       loginForm.show();
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
       //Log.p(e.toString());
   }
   ```

   }

Result - the same blank screen.

1. Same code with added Log.p and Log.send() statements.

Result - it works fine

Is this due to some race condition?